# How can I efficiently remove non-finite values from a Vaex DataFrame with many columns?

Tags: python, vaex

My data has values that are equal to positive and negative infinity. Vaex has functions to `dropna`, `dropmissing` and `dropnan` but not for removing non-finite values.

My current approach is to iterate through each column of interest and overwrite filtered datasets that remove the non-finite values from each column:

```
...
for col in cols:
   df = df[df.col.isfinite()]
...
```

While this approach does give me the correct result it appears to be very inefficient because it takes a long time to run, even when my dataset has only a few rows and a few thousand columns.

What is the preferred way to remove rows with non-finite values in Vaex?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a working example to demonstrate the slowness that I'm encountering on even a trivial dataset:

```
import vaex
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#create a dummy data frame with 1000 columns and a few rows, some with nan/inf
arr= []
for i in range(1000):
    arr.append([1] * 1 + [2] * 1 + [3] * 1 + [0] * 1 + [np.inf] * 1 + [-np.inf] * 1 + [np.nan] * 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = df.columns.map(str)
df = df.add_prefix('a')

df = vaex.from_pandas(df)

#eliminate rows that are not finite
for col in df.columns.keys(): #<-- this loop takes several minutes to run, I would expect it to be nearly instantaneous
    df = df[df[col].isfinite()]
df
```

**UPDATE 2**:
With some slightly different values in the cells and an alternative method for selecting finite records that works quickly but returns the incorrect results:

```
import vaex
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr= []
for i in range(2):
    if i == 1:
        arr.append([np.inf] * 1 + [2] * 1 + [3] * 1 + [0] * 1 + [1] * 1 + [1] * 1 + [1] * 1)
    else:
        arr.append([1] * 1 + [2] * 1 + [3] * 1 + [0] * 1 + [np.inf] * 1 + [-np.inf] * 1 + [np.nan] * 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = df.columns.map(str)
df = df.add_prefix('a')

df = vaex.from_pandas(df)
df
```

```
#   a0  a1
0   1   inf
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   0   0
4   inf 1
5   -inf    1
6   nan 1
```

```
is_col_finite = np.array([df[col].isfinite() for col in df.columns.keys()])
all_finite = np.all(is_col_finite, axis=0)
df = df[all_finite]
df
```

```
#   a0  a1
0   2   2
1   3   3
2   0   0
3   inf 1
4   -inf    1
5   nan 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem you want to remove the rows which contain at least 1 non finite value.

Instead of filtering the `df` in each iteration of the for loop you can create a `to_keep` variable which will be a boolean mask:

- True == keep the row
- False == remove the row

```py
to_keep = None
for column in df.columns:
   if to_keep is None:
      to_keep = df[column].isfinite()
   else:
      to_keep = to_keep and to_keep

df = df[to_keep]
```

I tried this with the snippet you provided:

```py
import vaex
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = []
for i in range(1000):
    arr.append([1] * 1 + [2] * 1 + [3] * 1 + [0] * 1 + [np.inf] * 1 + [-np.inf] * 1 + [np.nan] * 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = df.columns.map(str)
df = df.add_prefix('a')

df = vaex.from_pandas(df)
```

1. filter in each iteration of the for loop: > 10 min (I killed it before the end since it took too much time)
2. using the `to_keep` feature: 3s

---

This concept of mask is pretty similar to your **UPDATE 2** with the advantage of having only one vector instead of having all the vectors and then using `np.all`

If you want to use your solution you have to do the following:

```py
is_col_finite = np.array([df[col].isfinite().values for col in df.columns.keys()]) # add .values to convert the vaex expression to a numpy array
to_keep = np.all(is_col_finite, axis=0)

df["to_keep"] = to_keep
df[df["to_keep"]]
```

This will print the expected output:

```
a0  a1  to_keep
2   2   True
3   3   True
0   0   True
```

Remark: I don't know why but I was not able to use directly `df[to_keep]` so I had to add a column with the mask

---

Here is the version of my vaex packages:

```
vaex==3.0.0
vaex-arrow==0.5.1
vaex-astro==0.7.0
vaex-core==2.0.3
vaex-hdf5==0.6.0
vaex-jupyter==0.5.2
vaex-ml==0.9.0
vaex-server==0.3.1
vaex-viz==0.4.0
```